# XML to excel error

Tags: xml, excel, corrupt

I've been importing various XML files to excel, which it does fine, but once i save and close the spread sheet and re-open it again to import other XML files an error occurs. The error is below.

> 'The operation cannot be completed because the XML map is corrupt. To
>   fix this problem, remove the associated XML map from the workbook and
>   then add the XML map back to the workbook.'

When i try to remove it by clicking on the 'Source' button in the XML category on the ribbon the error appears again.

Anyone have any suggestions??

Comment: Off topic; nothing to do with programming. Belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 5):

One way to delete the map is in "Immediate" window of VB Page (Developer Macros Edit),
enter the following command:

```
thisworkbook.XmlMaps(1).Delete
```

Then, what I've found is one needs to import a schema with no "includes", which means flattening out the XSD files into one big XSD file.

Hope microsoft fixes this, because it's a pain!